# JS - how to get text content from a node as it is displayed on the page

Tags: javascript

Small reproducible code:

```
<div id="box">
    abc 
    <b>def</b>
    <p>ghi</p>
    jk
    lm
    <div style="color: green;">
        nop
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    let boxElement = document.getElementById("box");
    
    let processChildNode = function(htmlElement)
    {
        let childNode = htmlElement.firstChild;
        while (childNode) 
        {
            switch(childNode.nodeType)
            {
                case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
                    processChildNode(childNode);
                    break;
                case Node.TEXT_NODE:
                    let plainText = childNode.nodeValue;
                    console.log(plainText);
                    break;
            }
            
            // Gets next node
            childNode = childNode.nextSibling;
        }
    };

    processChildNode(boxElement);
</script>
```

Result on the rendered page in the browser:

[image: Rendered page]

Result in the debug console:

```
innerText.html:27 
        abc 
        
innerText.html:27 def
innerText.html:27 
        
innerText.html:27 ghi
innerText.html:27 
        jk
        lm
        
innerText.html:27 
            nop
        
innerText.html:27
```

Issue is most apparent in the case of "jk" and "lm".
There is a new line between them in the debug console, not in the rendered page...

I noticed "innerText" can do it for me but this variable is not available in node element.
How can I fix that?

ps.

For me it is important to process the node separately.
I can't do that:

```
console.log(boxElement.innerText)
```

Comment: have you tried `node.textContent`?

Comment: @DieterRaber Yes, result is the same as with "nodeValue".

Comment: I didn't find a direct solution, but replaced your `console.log` with `console.log({ plainText, processed: plainText.replace(/\s+/gs, " ").trim() });`. Not sure though if this is what you need.

Comment: This is a simple solution and I found no other issues, thanks!

Comment: I make this a proper answer for the benefit of future users.

Comment: This sounds like some design problem. In most cases you shouldn't rely on the information about how the page is rendered. It is up to the browser and you should not take for granted for how it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is no native method to solve this problem. If your concern is just about getting rid of the white space you could do this:

```js
switch(childNode.nodeType){
    case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        processChildNode(childNode);
        break;
    case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        let plainText = childNode.nodeValue.replace(/\s+/gs, " ").trim();
        console.log(plainText);
        break;
}
```